# How To access a field from a Map Value?

Tags: apex, integration, map, casting

I have an Object (ObjectA), which I have an important field called Motive. For every value in this field 'Motive', I'll have to send this 'ObjectA' to an external endpoint, changing accordingly with the 'Motive' value. Every motive value has a different endpoint.

I created A Custom Metadata Type to hold the external Id, with the same values of the Motive field and the linked external endpoint.

In the Apex Class, I'll need to get the right motive and endpoint and created a Map for that:

```
Map<ObjectA, Cmdt> Sending = New Map<ObjectA,Cmdt>();
Sending.put(QueriedA, QueriedMdt);
```

After this, I need to cast the value of the 'Mdt.ExternalField__c' to a String, to pass to the other Method, which will concatenate the endpoint with the 'Mdt.ExternalField__c', to send to the right place in the legacy system.

How to access the value of a field, on the value side of a Map structure?

Example:

```
String Endpoint = QueriedMdt.ExternalId__c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the field Motive (probably Motive__c) from the record QueriedA, you can do:

```
QueriedA.get('Motive__c');
```

that will return an object, so you will need to cast.
I hope this helps.

Comment: badges
Can't Make this work @Michel, to be more clear, I need to access a field, from the custom metadatatype, and when I try your code, it says the variable Motive doesn't exists. I made as it follows: 

`String endpoint = Queriedmdt.get(Motive__c)`

Comment: @Growred It's a String, as in `'Motive__c'`.

Comment: @Growred, Follow the comment above from sfdcfox. Consider also to use SObject as your generic type instead of Object to store the Metadata retrieved.